# How to club all insert scripts into a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some 4 tables

Source ---temp1---temp2----temp3--final table

have created all insert scripts  + some temporary tables for deriving the final result set into the final table.

Need to create a oracle procedure/functions as deemed necessary.

need a sample to incorporate the same..Should be super easy for the experts.

Thanks

Comment: *"Should be super easy for the experts"* -  for future reference it is "super easy" to find samples by looking in [the Oracle documentation (link)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54__BABDIJJC). I presume this is a homework assignment. I hope so. Because a flow like this smells of bad practice and should be a red flag in a real life scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think this shouldn't deter me from asking questions whether its super easy,super complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like this, I presume.

```
create or replace procedure p_insert is
begin
  --  all your insert statements go in here
  insert into temp1 (col1, col2, ...)
    select a.col1, b.col2, ...
    from a join b on a.id = b.id
    where ...;

  insert into temp2 (col1, col3, ...)
    select ...
    from temp1
    where ...;

  etc.

  insert into final_table (col1, col2, col3, ...)
    select ...
    from temp3;
end;
```